# Growth of Fourier coefficients of piecewise linear function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f$ is a periodic continuous piecewise linear function. What can be said about the growth (or decay, rather) of the Fourier coefficients $\hat f(n)$ as $n\to\infty$, other than the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma result that these coefficients go to zero?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in any classical book. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

In the link I shared in the comments section you can see that the following holds:

1. If $f$ is absolutely continuous, 
   $$
   \left| \widehat f(n) \right| \le {K \over |n|}.
   $$
2. If $f$ is a $BV$ function,
   $$
   \left|\widehat f(n)\right|\le {\|f\|_{BV}\over 2\pi|n|}.
   $$
3. If $f \in C^p$,
   $$
   \left|\widehat{f}(n)\right|\le {\| f^{(p)}\|_1\over |n|^p}.
   $$
4. If $f\in C^p$ and $f^{(p)}$ has modulus of continuity $\omega$,
   $$
   \left|\widehat{f}(n)\right|\le {\omega(2\pi/n)\over |n|^p}.
   $$
5. If $f$ is Hölder, (i.e. $f \in C^{0,\alpha}$),
   $$
   \left|\widehat{f}(n)\right|\le {K\over |n|^\alpha}.
   $$

A good reference to start with is [Fourier analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069111384X) by Stein and Shakarchi.

Comment: @Bungo I find all their books to be great!